# SQL Joining on Field with Nulls

Tags: sql, join, string-matching

I'm trying to match two tables where one of the tables stores multiple values as a string.

In the example below I need to classify each product ordered from the #Orders table with a #NewProduct.NewProductId.

The issue I'm having is sometimes we launch a new product like "Black Shirt", 
then later we launch an adaption to that product like "Black Shirt Vneck".

I need to match both changes correctly to the #Orders table. So if the order has Black and Shirt, but not Vneck, it's considered a "Black Shirt", but if the order has Black and Shirt and Vneck, it's considered a "Black Vneck Shirt."

The code below is an example - the current logic I'm using returns duplicates with the Left Join. 
Also, assume we can modify the format of #NewProducts but not #Orders.

```
IF              OBJECT_ID('tempdb.dbo.#NewProducts') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #NewProducts
CREATE TABLE    #NewProducts 
(
      ProductType VARCHAR(MAX)
    , Attribute_1 VARCHAR(MAX)
    , Attribute_2 VARCHAR(MAX)
    , NewProductId INT
)

INSERT      #NewProducts
VALUES
    ('shirt', 'black', 'NULL', 1),
    ('shirt', 'black', 'vneck', 2),
    ('shirt',  'white', 'NULL', 3)


IF              OBJECT_ID('tempdb.dbo.#Orders') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #Orders
CREATE TABLE    #Orders
(
      OrderId INT
    , ProductType VARCHAR(MAX)
    , Attributes    VARCHAR(MAX)
)

INSERT  #Orders
VALUES
    (1, 'shirt', 'black small circleneck'),
    (2, 'shirt', 'black large circleneck'),
    (3, 'shirt', 'black small vneck'),
    (4, 'shirt', 'black small vneck'),
    (5, 'shirt', 'white large circleneck'),
    (6, 'shirt', 'white small vneck')

SELECT      *
FROM        #Orders o
        LEFT JOIN #NewProducts np
            ON o.ProductType = np.ProductType
            AND CHARINDEX(np.Attribute_1, o.Attributes) > 0
            AND (
                    CHARINDEX(np.Attribute_2, o.Attributes) > 0
                OR np.Attribute_2 = 'NULL'
                )
```

Comment: This will not end well. Normalize your data or you will be in string matching hell (not even considering all the bugs and all the performance problems). You could have a `PRODUCTS`, a `PRODUCT_ATTRIBUTES` and a `ATTRIBUTES` table and then do something to the tune of `SELECT * FROM orders INNER JOIN products ON orders.product = products.id AND EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM product_attributes INNER JOIN attributes ON product_attributes.product = attributes.id WHERE product_attributes.product = products.id AND attributes.name = "Black") AND EXISTS (SELECT 1 ... WHERE attributes.name = "Vneck")`

Comment: This would be ideal but I'm at the mercy of the engineering team and they store the attributes field as a single string. 

I could make a temp #attributes table by breaking out the string though then use your method. Would that work?

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but just a comment. Because you have put quotes around `NULL` you will be inserting the word 'NULL' into the relevant places. That's not what `NULL` is meant for. You can leave the quotes off, but then you'll also need to make corresponding changes to code which looks for the `NULL`s.

Comment: Two immediate problems: "one of the tables stores multiple values as a string" and "Joining on Field with Nulls" i.e. your data violates 1NF, the most basic requirement of the relational model and ability to write a simple SQL query (chosen answer confirms this). Demand better of your engineering team!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to want the *longest* overlap:

```
SELECT *
FROM #Orders o OUTER APPLY
     (SELECT Top (1) np.*
      FROM #NewProducts np
      WHERE o.ProductType = np.ProductType AND
            CHARINDEX(np.Attribute_1, o.Attributes) > 0
      ORDER BY ((CASE WHEN CHARINDEX(np.Attribute_1, o.Attributes) > 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) +
                (CASE WHEN CHARINDEX(np.Attribute_2, o.Attributes) > 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
               ) DESC
     ) np;
```

I can't say I'm thrilled with the need to do this.  It seems like the `Orders` should contain *numeric* ids that reference the actual product.  However, I can see how something like this is sometimes necessary.

Comment: This must be close @GordonLinoff, but I get the error `The ORDER BY clause is invalid in views, inline functions, derived tables, subqueries, and common table expressions, unless TOP, OFFSET or FOR XML is also specified.`

Comment: @SteveLovell . . . There should be a `TOP (1)` in there, because you only want one matching row.

Comment: This works. It's slow but it'll get the job done. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't get Gordon's answer to work, and was part way through my own response when his came in. His idea of taking the biggest overlap helped. I've tweaked your `NewProducts` table, so that that side of things is "normalised" even if the `Orders` table cannot be. Code below or at [rextester.com/ERIF13021](http://rextester.com/ERIF13021)

```
create table #NewProduct
(
NewProductID int primary key,
ProductType varchar(max),
ProductName varchar(max)
)

create table #Attribute
(
AttributeID int primary key,
AttributeName varchar(max)
)

create table #ProductAttribute
(
NewProductID int,
AttributeID int
)

insert into #NewProduct
values (1, 'shirt', 'black shirt'),
       (2, 'shirt', 'black vneck shirt'),
       (3, 'shirt', 'white shirt')

insert into #Attribute
values (1, 'black'),
       (2, 'white'),
       (3, 'vneck')

insert into #ProductAttribute
values (1,1),
       (2,1),
       (2,3),
       (3,2)


select top 1 with ties
*
from
(
select
    o.OrderId,
    p.NewProductID,
    p.ProductType,
    p.ProductName,
    o.Attributes,
    sum(case when charindex(a.AttributeName,o.Attributes)>0 then 1 else 0 end) as Matches
from
    #Orders o
    JOIN #Attribute a ON 
    charindex(a.AttributeName,o.Attributes)>0
    JOIN #ProductAttribute pa ON
    a.AttributeID = pa.AttributeID
    JOIN #NewProduct p ON
    pa.NewProductID = p.NewProductID AND
    o.ProductType = p.ProductType
group by
    o.OrderId,
    p.NewProductID,
    p.ProductType,
    p.ProductName,
    o.Attributes
) o2
order by
row_number() over (partition by o2.OrderID order by o2.Matches desc)
```